# Using Repository Checks in conjunction with Azure Pipelines to ensure that a pipeline within the repository extends a template in a different repo?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

Let's say I have two repositories defined:

- `code`
- `templates`

In `code`, I have my application source code and an Azure Pipelines YAML file, `pipeline.yml`.

In `templates`, I have an Azure Pipelines YAML file, `template.yml`.

I want to set up a check at the `code` repository level to ensure that **all** pipelines within this repository extend `template.yml@templates`.

This feature *theoretically* exists.
I have it configured as follows:

`pipeline.yml` in `code` repo:

```
resources:
    repositories:
        - repository: templates
          name: templates
          type: git

extends:
    template: pipeline-template.yml@templates
```

`pipeline-template.yml` in `templates` repo:

```
trigger: none

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - script: echo Hello World
```

On the `code` repository, I have the template extension check configured as follows:
[image: template check]

My expectation, given this setup, is that when I run the pipeline, it fails because the pipeline does not extend an imaginary template named `xxxxxxx.yml`. However, the pipeline happily ignores the check and runs.

If I add an explicit `repository` resource for `code` to the template and explicitly check it out, the repository check fires as expected. However, this is **completely useless**, because it requires me to extend the template for the template check to function -- if I remove the `extends`, my pipeline runs, which defeats the purpose of having a required template.

It seems like there are two pre-requisites for this feature to work:

1. The pipeline must define a `resource` definition for the protected repository
2. The pipeline must explicitly have a `checkout` step for that repository.

I can't understand how this is correct behavior. If I have a repository protected, and a pipeline runs within that repository, shouldn't the repository check apply to the pipeline?

1. Am I somehow misconfiguring this feature, and if so, how to configure it to enable the scenario I described?
2. Am I wildly misunderstanding the purpose of this feature?
3. Is this feature is poorly implemented and/or has a known issue of which I am unaware?

Comment: I can only answer one of your questions: The feature works as expected, there is a 'self explanatory message when setting this up':  
Pipelines using this resource must extend at least one of the templates specified above. Which means, if another pipeline uses this specific repository, it *must* extend this template, I believe such scenarios is when you don't want to share the code with anyone else but you do allow them to use it. (Does it make sense? Not much IMHO).

Comment: @Bruno Yeah, I read the documentation and there's nothing indicating that it shouldn't work for this scenario. The repository is a resource (`self`) in the pipeline. The repository has a requirement that pipelines referencing it inherit a template. Yet the check isn't applied. The scenario in this case is that we want the pipeline definition itself to live in the repo, but allow the core pipeline logic to be owned and maintained by a separate team due to regulatory and auditing requirements. It's not exactly by-the-book devops, but it makes sense in that context.